# State can not be read in class, it's undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**My error:**
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'verified' of undefined at checkForVerifiedStatus`

**Part of my code:**

```
export default class Verification extends React.Component {
  state = {
    verified: false
  };

  verify = () => {
    this.setState({ verified: true });
  };

  shouldComponentUpdate() {
    return false;
  }

  render() {
    let timer = setInterval(checkForVerifiedStatus, 200);
    function checkForVerifiedStatus() {
      if (!uiStore.login.verified) return;
      else {
        this.verify;
        clearInterval(timer);
        console.log('verified ' + this.state.verified)
        return;
      }
    }
```

It seems like `this.state.verified` is not able to read the state value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: TL;DR `function` has its own context (`this`) which, in this case, is not the component, so `this.state` returns `undefined` throwing the error when trying to access `verified` on it.

Comment: `uiStore.login` is undefined. What should it be?

Comment: Is the error happening with `this.state.verified` or `uiStore.login.verified`?  It's not clear from your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change

```js
function checkForVerifiedStatus() {
// some code here
}
```

to

```js
const checkForVerifiedStatus = () => {
// some code here
}
```

what's happening here is the declaration of your `checkForVerifiedStatus` has its own context which when you call `this` would refer to the function itself, not the parent react class hence turning it into a arrow function automatically binds the context to the parent level which is your react component when refering to `this`

Comment: setInterval(checkForVerifiedStatus.bind(this), 200);

Comment: Oooh, here's you go! Work's perfect and I finally understand that.